# SQL Server 2000 where code= select code from

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using this code in SQL Server 2005 and it works.

```
select name 
from customers 
where code = (select code from inventory where Active = 1)
```

How can I do this in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: If only one code is returned that should work

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know what is better, your approach or an inner join: `select c.name from customers c inner join inventory i on i.code=c.code where i.active=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **IN**..With **=** If there is more than one code ,your query will fail

```
select name from customers where code in (select code from inventory where Active=1)
```

Comment: Doesnt `= (SELECT code...)` work in sql-server 2000 if only one code is returned?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, probably a data dependent issue, nothing to do with the SQL Server version used.

Comment: Cant i use inner join?

Comment: Works also with = .   It was needed just active=1.   I was used in my project active ='true'